# where to store password besides database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, passwords

i'm trying to build a super simple authentication. I'm not sure where to store admin password. Where should i put the password? Model, environment or somewhere else.? And how can i access enviroment variable if i store it in environment. THANKS!

UPDATE:

i put somethin in environment.rb

```
ADMIN_PASSWORD = "blablabla"
```

and trying to authenticate

```
def authenticate(username, password)
password = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(password).to_s
 if username == "admin" && password == ENV["ADMIN_PASSWORD"]
  session[:login] = true
 end
end
```

not working...

i think no need for to_s. Thanks all.

Comment: Write it on a piece of paper and hide it in a safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd prefer storing in Environment variables if database is not an option.

You can access them like

```
ENV["DB_PASSWORD"] # => "something_random"
```

Comment: Better is to have a config/admin.yml that can contain a list of valid password hashes and any other info you might want (ex permissions for each password)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an environmental variable, but you should use hashing to only set it encrypted. Try:

```
password = "abdefghij"
ENV['PASSWORD_SALT'] = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
ENV['PASSWORD_HASH'] = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, ENV['PASSWORD_SALT'])


def authenticate?(password)
  ENV['PASSWORD_HASH'] == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, ENV['PASSWORD_SALT'])
end

authenticate?("123456789") # false
authenticate?("abdefghij") # true
```

Comment: I'm confused. Can u give more detail ? what is my password in this example ?

Comment: You will initially set your ENV password using the first two lines, then can test if a password is correct using the provided method.

Answer (score 0):

Really simple would be to put it in a file, but don't forget to encrypt it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into HTTP Authentication? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#http-authentications